# Double meaning?

Tags: sentence-patterns, ambiguity, puns

Taken from "A Quiver Full of Arrows":

> "The flowers have lasted well," she
>   teased, and left him to make the
>   coffee.

Does the sentence clearly imply that ***she*** left to make the coffee? Or could it also imply that she left him so that ***he*** could make the coffee?

**Edit:**
The third sentence "She returned after a few minutes with a coffee pot..." makes the meaning abundantly clear. I just want to know how the first sentence stands up on its own.

Comment: I would state the second possible meaning as "she left *it* to him to make the coffee". I agree that the sentence is --possibly deliberately-- ambiguous.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case, the meaning is ambiguous and could mean either of the two you suggested as nothing in the phrase specifies who will be making it.  I originally read it as she was leaving to make the coffee, but both are equally plausible.  Is there any extra context around it that would clarify?  E.g. are they in a location where making coffee is possible?

Comment: please refer to the edit.

Comment: @crypto - got it and thanks.  Otherwise, I'm afraid my curiosity would have necessitated googling it for the context :P

Comment: +1 Dusty is right. Apart from any context, this sentence is perfectly ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

"She left to make the coffee" would be a considerably less ambiguous way of putting it!

I'm not sure we should *really* look to Jeffrey Archer as a model of literary style and clarity, you know... ;D

Comment: Some colleague of Mr. Archer in Parliament said, "Whenever I am looking for intellectual stimulation, I pick up one of Jeffery's books -- so I can stand on it to reach the good books."